# After Effects Track (Script) to Blender mismatches the scene and the video footage

Tags: scripting, tracking, external-applications

[Following this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MWZAdABvHA), I successfully tracked my footage in AE, which looked like a really good track.

I downloaded [ATOM_AE2Blender27_05302014.zip](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?232032-After-Effects-To-Blender-2-70a-Javascript-Python-Generator) from this website and ran that script successfully as the tutorial showed in AE.

When I returned to Blender 2.79 and opened up the output script AE returned, it set up a camera and my tracking scene. But when I opened up my footage as the camera background, the footage moves too slow and the scene too fast. I noticed the script put all its keyframes into 258 or so, and the video footage extended out a lot longer, up to 400 frames.

[image]

Why is my scene and "nulls" not aligned with the video footage? How do I re-align the scene to my video footage?

Comment: I didn't specify the correct amount of frames in AE, and after doing that, it fixed itself. I'll answer it after my time limit is up.

Comment: Blender has very powerful tracking tools. I suggest you use them instead of tracking in AE. It seems to me there is  a discrepancy in the frame rate (is the original footage using variable frame rate?) and how the project is set up in blender.

Comment: @Akados interested to see your answer :)

Comment: @cegaton I feel that Blenders tracking overall is good, but the automatic AE tracking yields me better results for just about any footage. Perhaps I just need more experience with Blender's manual tracking. (But Blender's auto-detect tracking points is absolutely terrible)

Comment: That would be awesome if you cared to share the answer you came up with and the AE version you were using. Thank you.